# Non differentiable function with partial derivatives?

Tags: partial-derivative, linearization

[Level curves of the considered function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6O1U.png)

Hello there,

I am having some trouble with the function defined by $f(x,y) = \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$ whenever $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and $f(0,0) = 0$.

On one hand the level curves diagram suggests the function is not differentiable at the origin.

Also, I can compute the partial derivatives $f'_x$ and $f'_y$  with the normal rules away from the origin, and by the definition (with the limit) at $(0,0)$, both are $0$. The partial derivatives seem to be continous, since what one obtains is a rational function having an homogeneous numerator of degree 5, and a denominator of degree 4.

But one knows that having continuous partial derivatives implies differentiability...

Can someone help, please?

Comment: The level curves suggest that there is a tripartite saddle point at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks,
I can see the saddle point, I can also plot the surface, and I can also compute the linearization of  $f$ at the origin. My problem is different, though : if the partial derivatives were continuous at $(0,0)$, as my computations suggest, then the function would be differentiable, that is locally linear. But the level curves suggest it is not, the linear approximation is the $0$ function.

Comment: The $0$ function is the correct linearization of the function. You could "stand" on the surface at $(0,0,0)$ because it is sorta flat there.

Comment: Yes, I get it. I will try to make my problem more clear: 

I have one argument that says that the function has continuous partial derivatives at $(0,0)$. This is computation. That would imply that $f$ is differentiable at the origin, meaning that the linearization is a good approximation, following Marsden - Tromba, for instance.

On the other hand, the level curves suggest that the function is not differentiable : near the origin, the level curves are not straight lines.

These two things cannot be simultaneously right. Which one is wrong?

Comment: Actually the level curves approach pairs of intersecting straight lines. I've created a demonstration of this for you on Desmos.com, just go to the following link and drag the slider for the level curve parameter $a$. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/teqdqsacxx

Comment: The function is differentiable, so it must be your intuition about level curves that is wrong. What exactly is it about the level curves that makes you think the function is non-differentiable at the origin?

Comment: You are right, @HansLundmark. My intuition was wring, indeed. What was wrong with the level-curves approach is probably that there is very little variation on the levels. When one makes the same figure that I posted, but showing the levels bar, one can see that there is almost no variation for the levels. Further, the level curves for the plane $z=0$ are not straight lines... So my intuition works inasmuch as the linearization is not the zero function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image of the surface as drawn by GeoGebra. It is actually a four part saddle point at (0,0,0):

[image: z=xy(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $|f(x,y)| = o(\sqrt {x^2+y^2}),$ then $Df(0,0)=0.$

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't actually answering my question.